# Am I considered Jewish if?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, judaism

my great-grandmother's grandparents were Russian Jews who left Russia during the programs in the early 1900s. When they came over to the United States, they had my great-great grandmother, who then married an Italian catholic man and had my great-grandmother who was raised into Catholicism but considers herself to be Jewish. Although her children were raised Catholic. Would I be considered Jewish? or has the line been broken?

Comment: Besides the fact that you didn't include information regarding whether you are a maternal descendant of your great-grandmother, when a family leaves Judaism for a certain number of generations, their descendants' Jewish identity would have to be re-validated with documents in a proper Jewish court of law (a beit din), should they be interested in re-joining a Jewish community. If they are unable to properly convince the court, they would have to convert (again, should they be interested in joining a Jewish community).

Comment: To clarify the documents would be to verify that they are Jewish because it is hard to know for sure whether someone 150 years ago was Jewish. And if they couldn't verify it, they would need to undergo 'giyur lechumra' - basically, they would have to go through conversion just to be careful, because if they can't verify that their ancestor was Jewish, we want to be careful that we don't end up with intermarriage. A beis din (rabbinic court) would decide if the person needed to bring documents to verify that they are Jewish, and if their proof is enough.